# Setting up Rsync to pull from Windows to Linux Box using cwrsync

Tags: linux, windows, cmd, synchronization, rsync

I have a set of machines, a mixture of Linux and Windows Boxes.

I hav set up rsync to pull from the Linux Machines to a Linux Server box.

I am trying to accomplish the same using cwRsync, to pull to the Linux box from the windows machines. I have downloaded the free version from https://www.itefix.no/i2/content/cwrsync-free-edition and also I have downloaded CopSSH. I have managed to install CopSSH fine and I am able to SSH between the Linux and Windows hosts no problem using keys rather than passwords.

However, for the life of me I can't get this cwRsync working, I've googled the matter to death, and your meant to unzip the directory, configure the environment settings in the batch file then install it. However, there is nothing to install it with! and the reason it isn't working is because it needs to install a windows service for it to run.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described at itefix web page for [the free edition](https://www.itefix.no/i2/content/cwrsync-free-edition), it allows to initiate rsync **from** your Windows machine, i.e. client functionality only (push data). Server functionality allowing you to set up an rsync server on Windows to pull data from it is not a part of the free edition.

Comment: Surely 'pulling files' shouldn't require the Windows machine to have server functionality. As it's still a client with the server pulling from it.

Comment: I have updated my answer to make client/server functionality specific to the Windows side (client - push, server - pull)

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing it up. I think your should, should make it a little clearer though.

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).